# What am I missing to make this initialization apply to multiple inheritance?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, initialization, multiple-inheritance

I was learning more about inheritance, and I came across this issue. I am trying to initialize inherited attributes that were inherited from multiple directions, or however you describe it.

The inheritance structure is: A is root, C is root, E inherits from A and C, then F inherits, from A and C and E.

A and C each have a member called `m_x`, which I've labeled `m_x` as the actual attribute and `x` as a getter/setter function with compile-time polymorphism. I know that's probably not good, but this is just an example I made for this question. E and F don't have their own members, just the inherited ones.

I want to initialize an object of F called `f` with these values:

- The `m_x` that it got from A: 1
- The `m_x` that it got from C: 2
- The `m_x` that it got from E, which E got from A: 3
- The `m_x` that it got from E, which E got from C: 4

It seems to initialize the values of the first two correctly, but I want to know what I'm doing wrong that makes the last two not match. Is what I am trying to achieve possible without changing the general inheritance structure? Adding classes if needed for some reason is fine.

I don't think the template parameters are the issue because I tried it without them and the same result happened.

Result:

```
1
2
1
2
```

Expected:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class A
{
    protected:
    T m_x;
    public:
    A(T x) : m_x(x) { }
    T x() { return m_x; }
};

template <class T>
class C
{
    protected:
    T m_x;
    public:
    C(T x) : m_x(x) { }
    T x() { return m_x; }
};

template <class T1, class T2>
class E : virtual public A<T1>, virtual public C<T2>
{
    public:
    E(T1 x_A, T2 x_C)
        : A<T1>(x_A)
        , C<T2>(x_C)
    { }
};

template <class T1, class T2, class T3, class T4>
class F : virtual public A<T1>, virtual public C<T2>, virtual public E<T3, T4>
{
    public:
    F(T1 x_A, T2 x_C, T3 x_E_A, T4 x_E_C)
        : A<T1>(x_A)              //also, is this kind
        , C<T2>(x_C)              //of indentation a
        , E<T3, T4>(x_E_A, x_E_C) //dumb idea?
    { }
};

int main()
{
    F<int, int, int, int> f(1, 2, 3, 4);
    std::cout << f.A::x() << '\n';
    std::cout << f.C::x() << '\n';
    std::cout << f.E::A::x() << '\n';
    std::cout << f.E::C::x() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's how I format initializer lists. Makes it easy to delete or comment any of them other than the first and it's easy to reorder if member order changes.

Comment: You might be trying too hard.  :-)  I have never, ever, seen a use case for multiple virtual inheritance. Learning exactly how that works might be a waste of your time. I bet you will likely never use it in practice, and I would save investigating the ugly details until forced to.

Comment: For longer initializer lists that span more than one line, I use the same initializer list indentation with the comma on the left-side.  Those who dislike that style probably consider it dumb (due to being grammarly contrary to normal writing rules... but programming is not normal writing).

Comment: @BoP If I remove "virtual" from all the base clauses then it generates a compile time error about how the base class is ambiguous.

Comment: @Patrick - Just saying that the odds are a million to one that you are never going to need this. So why bother? You don't *have to know* how it works.  I have been a developer since the 80's, and never seen a class with 3 virtual base classes.

Answer (score 2):

You used `virtual` inheritance and this is why your expectation is wrong.

> For each distinct base class that is specified virtual, the most derived object contains only one base class subobject of that type, even if the class appears many times in the inheritance hierarchy (as long as it is inherited virtual every time).

As for why its "1, 2, 1, 2" and not "3, 4, 3, 4":

> All virtual base subobjects are initialized before any non-virtual base subobject, so **only the most derived class calls the constructors of the virtual bases** in its member initializer list.